# CoinPayment GetExchangeRates Api Response Hnadling Issue

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am working on a Coinpayment.net api implementation.I am trying to get the CoinExhange Rates by Using GetExchangeRate Method, I am unable to Parese the Response. I want to get the list of all the coins rate but i dont know which response class i can use to and how for  getting the list of response.
Following is the Implementation i tried.

```
string result = string.Empty;
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_ApiReferenceLink);
                    var response = await client.GetAsync("GetExchangeRates");
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        ExchangeRatesResponse datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchangeRatesResponse>(result);
                        return Json(new { Message = "Your Transaction Has Been Completed Successfully!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(new { ErrorMessage = "Your Transaction Has Not Been Completed. Try Again Later!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
```

The above code dint gave me the response in object so that i can loop through and get the required coins price.

This is the responce that api will return to me i want to convert it to object so that i can access it using object.

```
{
  "error": "ok",
  "result": {
    "BTC": {
      "is_fiat": 0,
      "rate_btc": "1.000000000000000000000000",
      "last_update": "1375473661",
      "tx_fee": "0.00100000",
      "status": "online",
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "confirms": "2",
      "capabilities": [
        "payments",
        "wallet",
        "transfers",
        "convert"
      ]
    },
    "LTC": {
      "is_fiat": 0,
      "rate_btc": "0.018343387500000000000000",
      "last_update": "1518463609",
      "tx_fee": "0.00100000",
      "status": "online",
      "name": "Litecoin",
      "confirms": "3",
      "capabilities": [
        "payments",
        "wallet",
        "transfers",
        "convert"
      ]
    },
    "USD": {
      "is_fiat": 1,
      "rate_btc": "0.000114884285404190000000",
      "last_update": "1518463609",
      "tx_fee": "0.00000000",
      "status": "online",
      "name": "United States Dollar",
      "confirms": "1",
      "capabilities": []
    },
    "CAD": {
      "is_fiat": 1,
      "rate_btc": "0.000091601308947890000000",
      "last_update": "1518463609",
      "tx_fee": "0.00000000",
      "status": "online",
      "name": "Canadian Dollar",
      "confirms": "1",
      "capabilities": []
    },
    "MAID": {
      "is_fiat": 0,
      "rate_btc": "0.000049810000000000000000",
      "last_update": "1518463609",
      "tx_fee": "0.00000000",
      "status": "online",
      "name": "MaidSafeCoin",
      "confirms": "2",
      "capabilities": [
        "payments",
        "wallet"
      ]
    },
    "XMR": {
      "is_fiat": 0,
      "rate_btc": "0.028198593333333000000000",
      "last_update": "1518463609",
      "tx_fee": "0.01000000",
      "status": "online",
      "name": "Monero",
      "confirms": "3",
      "capabilities": [
        "payments",
        "wallet",
        "transfers",
        "dest_tag"
      ]
    },
   "LTCT": {
      "is_fiat": 0,
      "rate_btc": "1.000000000000000000000000",
      "last_update": "1375473661",
      "tx_fee": "0.00100000",
      "status": "online",
      "name": "Litecoin Testnet",
      "confirms": "0",
      "capabilities": [
        "payments",
        "wallet",
        "transfers"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The Responce Object Class that i used is:

```
   public class ExchangeRatesResponse
    {

        public List<ExchangeRateItem> ItemsList { get; set; }
    }
    public class ExchangeRateItem
    {
        public string is_fiat { get; set; }
        public decimal rate_btc { get; set; }
        public int last_update { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int Confirms { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help would be greatlly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: "unable to" means what? What went wrong with your code? What is `ExchangeRatesResponse`? Is it your own custom object?

Comment: yes i tried to add my own custom class but it dint worked.

Comment: @ADyson i just want to have a whole list of response but i am unable to convert the json response in object format

Comment: Please get someone to proof-read your question ([for reasons outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer i updated my question to explain a bit more kindly reccheck again

Comment: I'll repeat, what went wrong with your code above? Did you get an exception, or some other unexpected behaviour? I'm guessing your C# object's structure doesn't match the JSON, but that's just a guess, because you didn't tell us what the exact problem is, and the code is incomplete because we don't know what `ExchangeRatesResponse` is. I already asked all that in the first comment, and you haven't answered, just repeated yourself.

Comment: I'm not talking about the technical aspects, I'm talking about the horrendous number of spelling mistakes, punctuation errors and wrong capitalization on almost every second word.

Comment: @ADyson Unable means i dont know how i can convert the response into an object so i can loop through it

Comment: ok so that's the first of my three questions answered.... Basically you need to make an object whose structure matches the JSON. For the 3rd time, if you show us what you've done and explain what goes wrong with it, we might be able to help you in more detail.

Comment: @ADyson you are right m c# object is not according to response. i added the api expected response in question description. kindly guide me how i can create the response class to get the desired object

Comment: The properties and hierarchy need to match, that's all there is to it really.  The deserialiser uses a fairly simple name-and-structure based convention to match the JSON objects/arrays/properties to C# objects/lists/properties. Show us your current attempt, maybe it's nearly right and we can fix it easily.

Comment: @ADyson i pasted everything that i did in code so far. i also pasted the api expected response in question kindly see the question plz

Comment: No, you didn't, you forgot the code for `ExchangeRatesResponse` which is the thing you're deserialising to, and therefore the most important bit of the code, since that's the thing you're having trouble with.

Comment: @ADyson just added the Response class that i tried to use kindly see

Comment: ok well nothing will ever deserialise to a `List<>` because the JSON contains only objects, and not arrays (with the exception of "capabilities", but you don't seem to be interested in that bit).

Comment: so what should i do to deserialise it

Comment: `result` is a single object containing several properties such as `BTC`, `LTC`, `USD` etc. So make something which matches that.

Comment: I only need the coin name, rate_fiat and rate_btc

Comment: can you please post any small example i am stucked at this point

Comment: @TamourAli I posted a sample data structure

Answer (score 0):

Your C# object's structure does not match the JSON. Nothing will ever deserialise to a `List<>` because the JSON contains only objects, and not arrays (with the exception of "capabilities", but you don't seem to be interested in that bit). `result` is a single object containing several properties such as BTC, LTC, USD etc. So you need to make something which matches that.

Off the top of my head (untested), this should be more like it:

```
public class ExchangeRatesResponse
  public ExchangeRateResult result { get; set; }
  public string error { get; set; }
}

public class ExchangeRateResult
{
  public ExchangeRateItem BTC { get; set; }
  public ExchangeRateItem LTC { get; set; }
  public ExchangeRateItem USD { get; set; }
  public ExchangeRateItem CAD { get; set; }
  public ExchangeRateItem MAID { get; set; }
  public ExchangeRateItem XMR { get; set; }
  public ExchangeRateItem LTCT { get; set; }
}

public class ExchangeRateItem
{
    public string is_fiat { get; set; }
    public decimal rate_btc { get; set; }
    public int last_update { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int confirms { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help and great-full for bearing my auckward questions. the solutions works for me. thanks

Comment: @TamourAli No problem. In that case please remember to mark the answer as "accepted" and/or upvote it - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can parse through this using LINQ. Add the directive below to your class.

using System.Linq;

This method will return the list you were requesting.

```
public List<ExchangeRateItem> ParseAndReturnExchangeRateItemList(string jsonString)
    {
        //parse JSON and grab it's children. 
        var JSONobj = JObject.Parse(jsonString).Children();

        //turn into dictionary of property name and value
        var dictionary = JSONobj
            .Select(s => (s as JProperty))
            .ToDictionary(u => u.Name, v => v.Value);

        var ExchangeRateToExchangeDetailsDictionary =
            //grab result, maybe in another line grab error to make sure none exist. 
            dictionary["result"]
            .Select(s => (s as JProperty))
            .ToDictionary(u => u.Name 
            ,v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchangeRateItem>(v.Value.ToString()));

        //you iterate through your dictionary like this
        foreach (var kvp in ExchangeRateToExchangeDetailsDictionary)
        {
            //this is just string key of the exchangeRateCode
            var exchangeRate = kvp.Key;
            //this will return the ExchangeRateItem object. 
            var exchangeRateDetails = kvp.Value;
        }
        //you can also get the ExchangeRateItem object per exchangeRate like this
        var giveMeUSExchangeRate = ExchangeRateToExchangeDetailsDictionary["USD"];

        //if you need to just return a list of ExchangeRateItem objects you can do this
        List<ExchangeRateItem> listOfExchangeRateItem = ExchangeRateToExchangeDetailsDictionary.Values.ToList();
        return listOfExchangeRateItem;
    }
```

You can call it and feed it your JSON result.

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    ExchangeRatesResponse datalist = ParseAndReturnExchangeRateItem(result);
    return Json(new { Message = "Your Transaction Has Been Completed Successfully!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: yes you could, but why bother when JSON.NET will do it for you with one line of code?

Comment: @ADyson I see what you're saying, but this way he won't have to create a property for each exchange rate. He can just access them using the dictionary. I assume he'll want to know what the exchange rates names are at some point.

Comment: Possibly, although it wouldn't be too hard to add them to a list after deserialisation, without doing a semi-manual deserialisation. Possibly something like AutoMapper could be employed too to turn it into a nicer structure. Ultimately of course the real issue is that the JSON format is a bit silly :-).